# Limit MySQL Users' CPU/memory usage

Tags: mysql, memory, cpu

We are going to allow many users to access to a MySQL database. Each use has his/her own tables. We are going to set limitations on each user's CPU/memory usages. For instance, each use can't use more than 15% CPU and 512M memory. What are the best practice to achieve this goal?

Our operation system is Windows Server 2012. As much as we know, windows has the abilities to set CPU/memory usage limitation on the process level. However, all users share the same process in our scenario. Can we limit users' CPU/memory consumption by configuring MySQL?

Comment: I dont know of anyway on how to do this. I dont think it is even possible and limiting the resources is going to create severe bottle necks at some point. You could download the MySQL source code and fork it I suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not exactly what you are (or were) looking for, but for MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 at least, there are ways to limit:

-The number of queries an account can issue per hour

-The number of updates an account can issue per hour

-The number of times an account can connect to the server per hour

-The number of simultaneous connections to the server by an account

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-resources.html for more info.

I can't seem to find a CPU/memory locked solution, but will update this post if I find one.

Comment: 2022 is calling.. almost 2023, any news about it maybe? :D